# do not know how to convert 'outcome[, col]' to class “Date”

Tags: r

I wrote the following script in R software in order to converting date format in a prospective cohort data. But, I get an odd error. Could everyone help me? Any idea?

Code:

```
for(col in colnames(outcome)){
  if(startsWith(col, "eventdate_")){
    outcome[, col] <- as.Date(outcome[, col],"%Y-%m-%d")
  }
}
```

Error: 
Error in as.Date.default(outcome[, col], format = "%Y-%m-%d") : 
  do not know how to convert 'outcome[, col]' to class “Date”

Comment: why are you going about it in a `for` loop?

Comment: For applying on all time variables. Do you have any suggestion? TNX

Comment: is it in character format? if so, you can `gsub` `eventdate_` with `""` so that you only have the dates. then you can use the `as.Date` function on the character date

Comment: what is `class(outcome)` and what is the format of the `col`s you are trying to convert to date?  Also see [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ Adam Spannbauer  outcome is a csv file name contain date variables. col is date as yyyy-mm-ddformat

Comment: lubridate is a pretty standard package that converts the date into any format requested (ymd, dmy, etc.).